# Как выбрать данные из JSON средствами angular.js

Tags: html, json, angularjs

Добрый день всем. Есть код, который выводит данные из jsonовского файла на страницу. Но он выводит полностью все содержимое файла. Мне требуется отсортировать данные. К примеру что бы выводилось всё где в блоке встречается ID "000000001". Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать. Заранее благодарен!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="countryApp">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Монитор готовности</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
  countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
   $http.get('test.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.countries = data;
   });
  });
 </script>
<style>
progress::-ms-fill {   border: none; }
progress[value="100"]::-ms-fill {   background-color: #aaff00; }
</style>

</head>
<body ng-controller="CountryCtrl">
 <h2>Монитор готовности объектов</h2 >
 <table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Объекты</th>
   <th>Процент готовности</th>
   <th>Ввод в эксплуатацию</th>
   <th>Текущее состояние</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="country in countries ">
   <td>{{country.ID}}</td>
   <td>{{country.Obj}}</td>
   <td><meter id='p' max='100' value={{country.proc_gotov}}></meter>{{country.proc_gotov}}%</td>
   <td>{{country.vvod}}</td>
   <td>{{country.current}}</td>

  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- содежимое test.json -->
 [
  {
   "ID": "000000001",
   "Obj": "Данные об объекте 1",
   "proc_gotov": "100",
   "vvod": "01.10.2017",
   "current": "В процессе"
  },
  {
   "ID": "000000001",
   "Obj": "Данные об объекте 1",
   "proc_gotov": "100",
   "vvod": "01.11.2017",
   "current": "В процессе"
  },
  {
   "ID": "000000001",
   "Obj": "Данные об объекте 1",
   "proc_gotov": "100",
   "vvod": "01.12.2017",
   "current": "В процессе"
  },
  {
   "ID": "000000002",
   "Obj": "Данные об объекте 2",
   "proc_gotov": "10",
   "vvod": "01.05.2018",
   "current": "В процессе"
  },
  {
   "ID": "000000002",
   "Obj": "Данные об объекте 2",
   "proc_gotov": "10",
   "vvod": "01.05.2018",
   "current": "В процессе"
  },
  {
   "ID": "000000003",
   "Obj": "Данные об объекте 3",
   "proc_gotov": "100",
   "vvod": "01.12.2016",
   "current": "Готов"
  },
  {
   "ID": "000000003",
   "Obj": "Данные об объекте 3",
   "proc_gotov": "100",
   "vvod": "01.12.2016",
   "current": "Готов"
  },
  {
   "ID": "000000003",
   "Obj": "Данные об объекте 3",
   "proc_gotov": "100",
   "vvod": "01.12.2016",
   "current": "Готов"
  }

 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставьте фильтр:

```
<tr ng-repeat="country in countries | filter: { ID: '000000001' }">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! То что нужно!